# Minecraft Lan Commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My aunt and I were playing on her LAN World and she put on commands/cheats for both of us and I tried some commands I know and it said you don't have permission to do this and I did /help and the only commands that showed up were `/seed`, `/me (action)`, `/tell`, and `/w (whisper to another player)`.Why is this happening? Is it a bug or what?

We are playing MC version 1.7.10.

Comment: hi guys I need help and it just started when I got the version

Comment: What commands did you try to use?

Comment: What kind of LAN server is it? Does your Aunt use the "Open to LAN" option or does she run a full server, i.e. "minecraft_server.1.7.10.jar"? The correct answer will depend strongly on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because the server commands are limited to Ops of the server. Your Aunt will need to add your Minecraft username to a text file called `"ops.txt"` located in the server files.

As for it only happening in the current version, I've searched around a bit but couldn't find anything specifying a change related to this but my guess is that when the server upgraded to the current version the settings were reset, whether this was intentional or not I don't know.

Adding the name to the `"ops.txt"` should work though.

Comment: Additionally you can achieve this in game by any current op using the "op [player name]" command

Comment: the `/op` command is only available in a multiplayer session hosted by a server running the multiplayer server jar (and that goes for the `ops.txt` file too). It is not available in a single player world that has been "opened to LAN" (though it would be nice if Mojang did add feature parity here). The only option is to "enable cheats" on the "open to LAN" GUI screen as described in user213870's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create the world with cheats allowed, then open to LAN in the settings once in the world  and allow cheats! Then you both will have commands. To make it so you have more commands download "moreCommands mod" add to  .MineCraft/mod folder then it will give you the commands that you want like a server has such as /home /back and 100+ more commands depending what version of MC you are running!